# How to create the GET and POST methods 'CreateOrEdit()' to be redirected to CreateOrEdit.cshtml both when clicking on Edit and on Create New?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am trying to customize a POST and GET method called CreateOrEdit(int id, Request request) inside of the controller so that when I am in the Index view which is a list of requests generated from a SQL Table and I click either on the Edit button on the right of each row or on the Create New button, I am redirected to the same View which I have called CreateOrEdit.cshtml. I have managed to make the configuration on RouteConfig.cs but I don't how to come up with an 'if - else' condition in order to check whether id is null or is a number. Someone could help me on solving this?

P. s.: Maybe this is children easy but today is my 9th day as a developer guys :)

I have tried:
1. Add another 2 routes.MapRoute() inside RouteConfig.cs
2. Inside the ActionResult CreateOrEdit() GET and POST methods tried to add a condition in order to know whether id != null but it doesn't seem to help.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(int? id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(int? id, Request request)
{       
    if (/* id is not null (Edit has been clicked) */)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbModels dbModel = new DbModels())
                {
                    dbModel.Requests.Add(request);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Ketu shtojme logjiken e update-imit
                using (DbModels dbModel = new DbModels())
                {
                    dbModel.Entry(request).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: so you want to return same view for both operation or you have created different view?, what is your URL for createnew and Edit button. please post it as well.

Comment: Hi Vishal! I want to return the same view for both of them. If the Edit button is clicked, id != null. I will have all request data in editable format in the same form as Create.cshtml and I have already called it CreateOrEdit.cshtml. Their URL is :

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Create",
                url: "{controller}/create",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "CreateOrEdit" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Edit",
                url: "{controller}/edit/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "CreateOrEdit" }
                );

Comment: No matter the URL, the action remains CreateOrEdit both for Request/create and for e. g. Request/edit/7

Comment: so, when you are posting your code, you are post method is not calling? or your id value is not working in if condition.

Comment: You need to change your if or else code

Comment: you think if(id == null) solves this problem ?

Comment: have you checked ?

Comment: Hi Mr. Modi! I tried the followubg:

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateOrEdit (int? id, Request request)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DbModels dbModel = new DbModels())
                    {
                        // No id so we add it to database
                        if (id == null)
                        {
                            dbModel.Requests.Add(request);
                        }

Comment: // Has id, therefore it's in database so we update
                        else
                        {
                            dbModel.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }

                        dbModel.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            return View(request);
        }

Comment: but now I am not sure how to customize the RouteConfig.cs

Comment: it gives me this error: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Request/CreateOrEdit      when I click either on 'Create New' or on 'Edit' . Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

first your condition is wrong. so just change your condition and then try.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(int? id, Request request)
    {

        if (id == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DbModels dbModel = new DbModels())
                    {
                        dbModel.Requests.Add(request);
                        dbModel.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // Ketu shtojme logjiken e update-imit
                    using (DbModels dbModel = new DbModels())
                    {
                        dbModel.Entry(request).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                        dbModel.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        return View();
    }**strong text**
```